# Get IPAddress C#

Tags: c#, ip-address

How do I get the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR Ip Address?

1. HTTP CLIENT IP

   HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.ToString();
2. HTTP X-FORWARDED FOR //proxy ip address

   ?
3. REMOTE ADDRESS

   ?

Comment: More information, such as what technology you're using (IIS, your own custom HTTP server, a reverse proxy?) would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163692.aspx for retrieving the so-called "server-variable" HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR from a http request...

For an explanation see http://forums.asp.net/t/1138908.aspx